# CSS: Not getting text popup

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to show popup message as illustrated in this [blog](http://mblfooter.blogspot.in/2012/07/test-it-out.html). I followed instructions exactly as described [here](http://www.mybloggerlab.com/2012/07/css3-popup-text-and-image-boxes-for.html). I applied in my blog and it is not working. Plese refer below script

```js
// Place all Javascript code here
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#showPopup").click(function() {
    $("div#Popup").addClass("show");
    return false;
  });
  $("#closePopup").click(function() {
    $("div#Popup").removeClass("show");
    return false;
  });
  $(".trigger").click(function() {
    $(".panel").toggle("fast");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
Popup {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  width: 560px;
  left: 170px;
  border: solid 1px #bbb;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  opacity: 0.0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.0s ease-out;
  z-index: 0;
}

div#Popup.show {
  opacity: 1.0;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s;
}

pre {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  margin: 0 0 18px;
  padding: 13px 18px 14px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #fff;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 16px;
  font: 12px/18px "Monaco", "Courier New", "Courier", monospace;
  color: #fff;
}

code {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  border: solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  border-width: 1px 1px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  font: 12px/18px "Monaco", "Courier New", "Courier", monospace;
}

.button {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
  background: #33AD33;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  padding: 1px 4px 1px 4px;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #327F32;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" id="showPopup" class="button">Show me The Message</a>
```

I am not getting any pop up. Please help.

Comment: You forgot to add your JSFiddle link.Please update.

Comment: Please add relevant code or fiddle link

Comment: You don't have a popup div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added the popup styling code but forgot to add the popup html code itself:

```
<div id="Popup">Hello there</div>
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ty9xp00e/)

Also note that as per your code, the popup element should be having the id `Popup`.
So the CSS code was changed from `Popup`to `#Popup`. Also I added code to close the popup on click and added a comment so you can distinguish between the added code.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks @Ahs N. Sorry was not aware of adding code.

Answer (score 0):

As instructed by @Pete you forget to add popup div.

> Here is the quick fix:

```js
// Place all Javascript code here
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#showPopup").click(function() {
    $("div#Popup").addClass("show");
    return false;
  });
  $("#closePopup").click(function() {
    $("div#Popup").removeClass("show");
    return false;
  });
  $(".trigger").click(function() {
    $(".panel").toggle("fast");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
#Popup {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  width: 560px;
  left: 170px;
  border: solid 1px #bbb;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  opacity: 0.0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.0s ease-out;
  z-index: 0;
}

div#Popup.show {
  opacity: 1.0;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s;
}

pre {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  margin: 0 0 18px;
  padding: 13px 18px 14px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #fff;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 16px;
  font: 12px/18px "Monaco", "Courier New", "Courier", monospace;
  color: #fff;
}

code {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  border: solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  border-width: 1px 1px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  font: 12px/18px "Monaco", "Courier New", "Courier", monospace;
}

.button {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
  background: #33AD33;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  padding: 1px 4px 1px 4px;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #327F32;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" id="showPopup" class="button">Show me The Message</a>

<div id="Popup">




dsadsadsadsdsdsacsacas
<a href="" id="closePopup">close ME</a>
</div>
```